# Equality between absolute value of inner products of orthogonal vectors and it's respective image under unitary transformations

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $u,v\in\mathbb{C}^2$. Let $u^\perp,v^\perp$ be vectors that are orthogonal to $u$ and $v$ respectively. Then $\{u,u^\perp\}$ and $\{v,v^\perp\}$ are two orthonomal basis of $\mathbb{C}^2$. Since the two are orthonormal basis, there is a unitary transformation $U$ such that $Uu=v$ and $Uu^\perp = v^\perp$. My question is: is true that $|\langle u,v \rangle|=|\langle u^\perp,v^\perp \rangle|$? Seems that is true, since this transformation is a rotation in the $\mathbb{C}^2$, but i couldn't prove it using algebra and the property that unitary transformation preserves inner product.

Comment: You probably meant $v=Uu$ and $v^\perp=U u^\perp$. In that case $\langle u,v\rangle=\langle U u^\perp, U v^\perp\rangle=\langle u^\perp, v^\perp\rangle$.

Comment: @P.Quinton Thanks! I corrected the question. Why is the case that $\langle u,v \rangle = \langle Uu^\perp,Uv^\perp \rangle$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*(You need to clarify that you are assuming unit vectors)*

Yes, this is true. Because the inner product is unaffected by applying a unitary, you may assume without loss of generality that $u,u^\perp$ are $e_1,e_2$, the canonical basis. Then you are asking if for orthonormal vectors $v,v^\perp$ you have
$$
|v_1|=|(v^\perp)_2|.
$$
And this works because the dimension is $2$. If we write $v=(x,y)$ and $v^\perp=(r,s)$, then we know that
$$
|x|^2+|y|^2=|r|^2+|s|^2=1,\qquad\qquad x\overline r+y\overline{s}=0. 
$$
It is not hard to show that the solutions to this system are of the form
$$
x=\lambda_x\cos t,\ y=\lambda_y\sin t,\qquad r=\lambda_r\sin t,\ s=\lambda_s\cos t,
$$
with $t$ real and $|\lambda_x|=|\lambda_y|=|\lambda_r|=|\lambda_s|=1$. In particular
$$
|\langle e_1,v\rangle|=\cos t=|\langle e_2,v^\perp\rangle|.
$$

Comment: Or more "directly": $|x|^2+|y|^2=|r|^2+|s|^2=1$ and $|xr|=|ys|$ imply $|x|\sqrt{1-|s|^2}=|s|\sqrt{1-|x|^2}$ i.e. $|x|=|s|.$

Comment: Now I see. I was trying to prove the general case, but it works only in dimension 2. Thank you very much. One more thing: the innerproduct is $x\overline{r} + y \overline{s} =0$ instead of $xr+\overline{ys}=0$, isn't?

Comment: Yet, that was a typo. It's edited now.